# How add rotating Carousel slider in SharePoint Office 365 site home page .

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, javascript, office-365, sharepoint-rest-api

As per My client requirement, they want in office 365 intranet site on home page rotating Carousel slider. I have no idea how to achive this using CEWP,using a library images. because I'm New in sharepoint 365.

Please suggest me with some link related this. 
   I want link Below images.

[image]

Comment: We have created SharePoint Framework responsive image slider webpart. This is a very useful webpart. Check from our store: https://www.nopvalley.com/sharepoint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initially used a typical Javascript carousel which worked fine, but maintenance of images, etc. was not suitable for non-techies. So after some digging switched over to [PAIT Slider](http://www.paitgroup.com/the-ultimate-content-slider-for-sharepoint).

It reads from an Promoted Links list and allowed for customization, etc.  My users could then manage the slide count, images and text simply by updating the list.  Uses the Description field to allow any HTML you want.  We used it to make a table with a footer that we place informational text and links.

```
<table style="width: 100%; height: 100%; text-align: center;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 100%;">
    <!-- slider image appears here as background -->
            </td>
        </tr>
    <!-- ↓ OPTIONAL IMAGE CAPTION ↓ -->
        <tr style="background: white; height: 50px; 
        border-top-color: #cdd0d4; border-top-width: 1px; 
        border-top-style: solid;">
            <td style="width: 100%;">
                <span>Caption text about your slide</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You still need to plant the images somewhere, so I tried adding this approach.
• Attach the image directly to the promoted list item used to configure the slide.
• Use a workflow to get the attachment path and name and put it in the field that defines the image address.
• Now the list can hold the slider caption, order configuration and the image. 
**Caution**: slider will show without an image if field is left blank while waiting the workflow to run. So be sure to use a default image for that space.

*not affiliated with PAIT in any way, just a lucky find :)

Answer (score 3):

**Option #1** - You can use Office 365’s new modern site page and **Highlighted content** web part.  The web part is only available on the new modern site page.

1. Go to the **Site Pages** library and click new page.
2. The new modern site page will open.
3. Add the **Highlighted content** web part to the page.
4. In the **Type** drop down select **Images**.
5. In the **Layout** section select **Carousel**.

**Option #2** - dd the **Content Search** web part or the **Pictures** web part to any web page – site page or web part page - and display an image slideshow/carousel. Large images are cropped to fit and display nicely.

When editing a web page the **Content Search** web part is usually in the **Content Rollup** category and the **Pictures** web part is usually in the S**earch-Driven Content** category.

1. Edit a web page.
2. Add the one of the two web parts to the page.
3. Edit the web part.
4. In web part settings, in the **Search Criteria** section click **Change Query**, then in the **Restrict by app** drop down select **Specify a URL** and enter your picture library’s URL. Click **Ok**.
5. In web part settings, in the **Display Templates** section, in the **Control** drop down select **Slideshow**, and in the **Item** drop down select **Large Picture**.

Comment: I preferred your 1st option but this not full page slider , if i want top of the page full page slider so how can we manage? you have any idea? .

Comment: Off the top of my head I dont' have any ideas.  Sorry Mohammad.  I'll leave another comment if I think of anything.  Good luck!

Comment: No Problem ,Thank you so much Jenny for your effort .